# Are orange striped tires available anywhere for 700x32 hybrid?

Tags: tire, hybrid-bike

I've been trying to find an orange striped or orange tire that is 700x32 for my hybrid bike to no avail. Is there such an animal or am I SOL?

Comment: I voted to close, since this is fundamentally a product recommendation/shopping question.  Unfortunately these go out of date quite quickly - clearly evidenced by the fact we have a similar question for 700x23 tyres from a number of years ago and all the answers are now useless because you can't buy them anymore.

Comment: That said, if you are really keen on orange and moving up to 700x35 is an option for you, there still seem to be some orange panaracer gravel kings to be had with a little googling.

Answer (score 1):

The orangish-looking tires are called "tanwall". With this magic keyword, I'm sure you are able to find quite many options. For example, Google search "tanwall 700 32" finds at least the following: [Panaracer Pasela 700 x 32](https://www.modernbike.com/panaracer-pasela-protite-tire-700-x-32-tire-folding-bead-black-tan) (not suggesting that this would be better than any other option).